# Foreign gift voucher not working

Tags: itunes, gift

I was given an iTunes gift voucher from the U.S. I'm australian and after poking around I realised I had to make a U.S. Apple ID. Once I had done this when I tried to purchase an item with this card, it says "Your purchase could not be completed" and behind that it says 'unable to connect to the Itunes store'. I'm not sure if this is a fault with me or with apple. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid US Apple ID, it should accept the US iTunes gift card.  It should not matter in which country you are physically.  I know because I do this myself.  Does your account show the correct balance, in other words was the voucher correctly processed?

I expect that there is just a small fluke and likely you should try again later to see if the purchase can be completed.